# How to find Thevenin's Equivalent Resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I am asked to find the thevenin equivalent of this circuit but I am having trouble. The solution says that:
Rth=2(RxRy)/(Rx+Ry)
Vth= (VxRy+VyRx)/(Rx+Ry)
Can someone please explain to me how to arrive at the solution.

[image: Circuit to Be Solved]

Comment: It's not always the case that a diagram alone is sufficient. The first question I had in mind was "Is RM included in this, or is it removed when attempting an answer?" Your provided solution tells me it is probably removed, though.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to find Thevenin's Equivalent Resistance*

Because of the two voltage sources, \$R_Z\$ is of no consequence and can be shorted out: -

[image]

Then you can short all the voltage sources out and see that \$R_{TH}\$ is simply the resistance looking into node A plus the resistance looking into node B: -

[image]

Given that both those nodes have the same value of resistors associated with them, the Thevenin resistance is simply \$R_X||R_Y + R_X||R_Y = \dfrac{2\cdot R_X\cdot R_Y}{R_X+R_Y}\$.

For the voltage, try seeing what I've done here: -

[image]

I'll leave the OP to solve this (easy to do using Millman's theorem): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://electricalvoice.com/millmans-theorem-limitations-applications/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just have a question. How is it that Rz can be shorted? I don’t really understand the concept.

Comment: Because whatever current flows through Rz has no bearing on the Thevenin resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I do is redraw a schematic that I am to analyze.

In your case, that looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGyH3G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This makes it a lot easier to see that \$R_{_\text{Z}}\$ can be ignored, as there isn't a way that it can affect the rest. It's essentially a separate circuit.

It's also a lot easier to see how the grounded pair of \$R_{_\text{X}}\$ and \$R_{_\text{Y}}\$ are in parallel with each other.

And, if you understand the Thevenin equivalent resistance of a resistor divider, you'll also see how the other pair of \$R_{_\text{X}}\$ and \$R_{_\text{Y}}\$ can also be treated as if they are in parallel with each other. (Though the Thevenin voltage at the other end will be a combination of \$V_{_\text{X}}\$ and \$V_{_\text{Y}}\$, of course.

Get into the practice of redrawing schematics. It will help a lot. Especially, as you get better at it.

Comment: The most significant common concept when it comes to these sort of questions, is, once again, emphasized by us both; draw and draw again... Get out pencil and paper (or laptop and paint.exe/a.n.other bit of software).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain how exactly it is that Rz can be ignored. I mean is there a general rule that can help me understand when I can apply this?

Comment: @RobertoGuarneros Well, first off just get an eraser and erase all the wires that are tied to ground and also to parts. Then just tie those part ends to ground, directly, instead. Having all kinds of parts going to and from ground is very confusing. But the same can also be done for everything tied to the other end of a power supply, too. If you erase all those wires and then just tie the parts directly to the supply with a simple "note", then you will have what I wound up with. Try it. (Oh, no need for the power supply elements, either. Dump the voltages and just use labels, instead.)